# Hand Off Bot to Human in azure bot framework SDK V4

Tags: sdk, botframework, handoff

Need solution on Bot to human handOff in azure botframework sdkv4 using nodejs

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.  Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2017/08/10/microsoft-bot-framework-handing-off-to-a-human-for-agentssupervisors-with-c-and-the-botbuilder-sdk/